# how to call a javascript function whenever an html code loads

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function addMore() {
 $("<div>").load("m_text.php", function() {
   $("#product").append($(this).html());
 }); 
}

the below html code with flate_rate function is in m_text.php
```

```html
<div class="float-leftt"><input type="number" name="saleable_area[]" id="isalable_area[]" placeholder="Salable Area" /></div>
    <div class="float-leftt"><input type="number" name="flat_rate[]" id="iflat_area[]" placeholder="Flat Rate"/ onkeyup="flat_rate()"></div>
    <div class="float-leftt"><input type="number" name="flat_cost[]" id="iflat_cost[]" placeholder="Flat Cost"/></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function flat_rate(){
    var salable_area = document.getElementById("isalable_area[]");
    var flat_area = document.getElementById("iflat_area[]");
    var flat_cost=[];
    var i=0;
    
     flat_cost[0] = salable_area.value*flat_area.value;
    alert( flat_cost[0]);
    document.getElementById("iflat_cost[]").value=(flat_cost[0]);
    }
</script>

add more code
<input type="button" id="add_button" name="add_item" value="Add More"  style="width:15%;" onClick="addMore();"/>
```

this code works properly when the html code runs first time. when user click on add more button this html code loads again at that time the calaculated value doesnt appear in flat cost .

If i use class instead of id then it shows NaN in output.
please help me. thank you

Comment: _"when user click on add more button this html code loads again at that time the calaculated value doesnt appear in flat cost"_ Are there elements having duplicate `id` within `document`?

Comment: no , i didnt mention any duplicate id

Comment: where is your add more ?

Comment: second time function works properly .. i got a calculated value in alert function but it dosent appear in text box. i am not getting why it happens

Comment: `document.getElementById("iflat_cost[]").value=(flat_cost[0]);` remove `=`

Comment: return the value to .innerHTML of element with id.

Comment: after removing this document.getElementById("iflat_cost[]").value=(flat_cost[0])‌​; the value dosent appear in text box.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example code, you can try this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function addMore() {
    $("#product").append($("div.block").html());
  }
</script>

<div id="product">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="input">
      <div class="float-leftt"><input type="number" name="saleable_area[]" id="isalable_area[]" placeholder="Salable Area" /></div>
      <div class="float-leftt"><input type="number" name="flat_rate[]" id="iflat_area[]" placeholder="Flat Rate"/></div>
      <div class="float-leftt"><input type="number" name="flat_cost[]" id="iflat_cost[]" placeholder="Flat Cost"/></div>
    </div>

    add more code
    <input type="button" id="add_button" name="add_item" value="Add More"  style="width:15%;" onClick="addMore();"/>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#product").on('keyup', "[name='flat_rate[]']", function(){
    var salable_area = $(this).parents("div.input").find("[name='saleable_area[]']");
    var flat_area = $(this);
    var flat_cost=0;

    flat_cost = salable_area.val()*flat_area.val();
    alert( flat_cost);
    $(this).parents("div.input").find("[name='flat_cost[]']").val(flat_cost);
  });
</script>
```

If you want to load file, you can take `<div class="block">...</div>` block to your file, then modify the add-more function:

```
$.get( "m_text.php", function( data ) {
    $("#product").append(data);
});
```

Comment: You meant not working on load()?
`$.get( "m_text.php", function( data ) {
      $("#product").append(data);
    });`

Comment: You can run my code snippet, after keyup on the second field, the result will show on third field in each block.